# What is "Could not find Test Containers for requested projects" message in VS output window?

Tags: visual-studio

When I build my VS2015 solution I'm getting "Could not find Test Containers for requested projects" in my output window. It's in the "Tests" output---which is getting displayed automatically on publishing my (MVC) projects.

This has only started happening recently.

I have some MSTest projects in the solution.

I'm using Resharper. I mention this as the only search hits I got on the message were pages about Resharper.

What do these messages mean and, more importantly, how do I get rid of them?

I have VS 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and Resharper 2016.2.2.

Comment: Funny, I also started getting this today. Seeing only this non-answered stackOverflow question does not give me hope :(

Comment: Indeed. Do you use Resharper?

Comment: I also have this problem, but for projects in VS2013.  I also use ReSharper.

Comment: My version of R# is 2016.2.2

Comment: Thanks. Same version as me. Added my current version numbers.

Comment: I use Resharper, also the latest version. It happens for some build configurations  but not for others, so might be related to that.

Comment: Closing and reopening Visual Studio fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems like the best solution currently is to disable MSTest support in Resharper.

Go to `Resharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | MsTest` and uncheck `Enable MSTest support`.

Solved the problem for a few people, but obviously disables the MSTest support you get with Reshaper. So, we have to decide on the lessor of two evils for now.

Answer (score 5):

I got rid of mine by

1. Navigating to Help | Register Product
2. Sign Out
3. Sign In

I have no idea why this worked for me, and no real good reason to have tried it in the first place.

Comment: Will give it a try. Didn't see the offending messages when I launched VS this time, but performed your procedure anyway. Let's see if it returns tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not seeing it now. I can't be sure it was signing in and out that did it, but worth a go. Maybe others can confirm when they try it.

Comment: It's returned. :( Seems to happen on publishing.

Comment: What I've now tried is disabling MSTest support in Resharper. Go to Resharper | IOptions | Tools | Unit Testing | MsTest and uncheck "Enable MSTest support".

Comment: @dommer well... except now I realize that it has disabled all of my unit tests... but at least I was able to publish my project

Comment: @dommer: Disabling MSTest worked for me also. You probably want to add that as a answer to this Stackoverflow question so it's more visible.

Answer (score 3):

As for me if i published in debug configuration - everything was ok. But with release i had the same problem. Next steps helped me:
- Switched to Release configuration
- Clean/rebuild solution
- Publish it